# setHint and setHintColor not working

Tags: android

I am making a app which sends the sms at the scheduled time. The schedule button perform the scheduling function. I have three text areas to get the user input. I want to reset these text area with the hints after I have pressed the schedule button. so, i have defined a function as:

```
           public void resetInputFields() {
    /**
     * Resetting the text box to their initial values
     * 
     * */
    bdayMsg.setHint("Type your Message here..");
    bdayMsg.setHintTextColor(R.color.text_grey);

    phoneNum.setHint("Recipients..");
    phoneNum.setHintTextColor(R.color.text_grey);

    setBirthdayButton.setHint("Date");
    setBirthdayButton.setHintTextColor(R.color.text_grey);

}
```

but setHint creates no effect while it works perfectly if i do the following:

```
   ublic void resetInputFields() {
    /**
     * Resetting the text box to their initial values
     * 
     * */
    bdayMsg.setText("Type your Message here..");
    bdayMsg.setTextColor(R.color.text_grey);

    phoneNum.setText("Recipients..");
    phoneNum.setTextColor(R.color.text_grey);

    setBirthdayButton.setText("Date");
    setBirthdayButton.setTextColor(R.color.text_grey);

}
```

Well my main problem is that i want to reset my text areas to hints not text...But i am not able to do so.... the text areas only get reset if i do setText.......
But i cant reset my text areas to hints .
So plz guys help me figure out whats the problem with the hints........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set the text to `""`
in that way the user will see the hints (hints are gone if the text different then "")

edit:

```
public void resetInputFields() {
    /**
     * Resetting the text box to their initial values
     * 
     * */
    bdayMsg.setText("");
    bdayMsg.setTextColor(R.color.text_grey);

    phoneNum.setText("");
    phoneNum.setTextColor(R.color.text_grey);

    setBirthdayButton.setText("");
    setBirthdayButton.setTextColor(R.color.text_grey);

}
```

Comment: @user102...i am sorry but i am really confused what u r trying to tell...i have put the text inside "".....can u clarify your answer a bit more

Comment: @user102.. i think u completely misunderstood my question.....the problem is actually with the setHint() and not with setText()

Comment: you can set hints - and if the user change the text - the hints are gone. if you set text in the fields obviously there will be no hints. for reset the edittext you need to put "" (empty string) in the text field and then the hint will be shown.

Comment: perfect... same issue happend with me +1 for your answer

Comment: I am not able to set the hint using setHint() after clearing out the text with setText("").

Answer (score 2):

try

```
bdayMsg.setHintTextColor(Color.GRAY);
```

Comment: that would change just text color. It doesn't affect hint in anyway.

Comment: I editted my answer form 
bdayMsg.setTextColor(Color.GRAY); 
to 
bdayMsg.setHintTextColor(Color.GRAY);

works for me unless edittext is focused.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right you just gave example of two cases, so I suppose you don't use both code samples at the same time..

Solution would be easy, but I am not sure about your layout settngs. Can you show us xml of that layout?

Usually I am setting hints in xml of layout using:

```
android:hint="Enter your name here"
```

and default color of hint is gray..This hint will appear again when user delete entered text or if you set it in one moment to empty string

**BUT** if u set text and hint from code at the same time, of course text has priority and hint will not be visible.

Hope it helped.

Comment: I will list out whats going on in my program: First- i set the hints Second - The user inputs their data and hence hints no longer exist. Third- The user presses the submit button and Fourth- The input areas are again reset with their hints...this is where my problem is...The text areas wont resset to hints So i try to reset them with text using the second case..and this works...but text is not what i want. I want Hints

Comment: Usually, when a developer uses the setHint() method, it is because the hint is going to be changes at some point. I am developing a program that causes the fields to be used differently depending on which radio button is selected. In this case, each time a radio button is checked, I need to dynamically change the hint. Defining the hint in the layout xml does not fit the scenario.

Comment: @James setHint is used to give user a clue what he should type in, and in her scenario it should always be the same therefore it's ok to set it in xml. If you have other scenario on your mind and issues about it, just ask new question and I will be glad to help. p.s. hopefully you didn't post it 4 years ago :))